# Remotely use CMDlet that's not on the remote pc

Tags: powershell, remote-connection, psexec

Hi i have a script using AudioDeviceCmdlets power shell module from Github.

the script runs fine its just a basic audio check, but i want to be able to run it against a machine that dosent have that module installed.

i tried Invoke-Commmand and PSexec, neither seem to work or I'm not using the right commands

```
Invoke-Command - FilePath *my file path* -ComputerName *ip address*   
Psexec \\*ip* -u *username* -p *password*
```

(every pc has the same name, large workgroup, 300+ pcs)

(i will be adding more to it, setting the correct default if not already set, im just having a hard time with the remote portion of this.

My Script i want to run remotely:

```
Get-AudioDevice -Index -1 | Format-List -Property Name,Default,Type
Get-AudioDevice -Index -2 | Format-List -Property Name,Default,Type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the module using `Import-Module` using a PSSession on the remote computer.

> You can manage remote Windows computers that have PowerShell remoting enabled by creating a PSSession on the remote computer. Then use the PSSession parameter of Import-Module to import the modules that are installed on the remote computer. You can now use the imported commands in the current session. The commands implicitly run on the remote computer.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7